# Requiring fields based on each other's value

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

[image: Screenshot]

I've got the field above, I want to require them to enter a value greater than 0 for at least one, but they can also have tables and seats.

My HTML:

```
   <div class="form-row reserve">
    <input type="text" name="tables" id="tables" value="0"/>
        <label for="tables">corporate tables (10 seats) @ $1,950 each and/or</label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-row reserve">
    <input type="text" name="individual" id="individual" value="0"/>
        <label for="individual">individual seats @ $225 each</label>
   </div>
```

I've tried this and it doesn't seem to be working:

```
tables: {
    required: function(element){
        return $("#individual").val() == 0;
    }
},

individual: {
    required: function(element){
        return $("#tables").val() == 0;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a function inside of a `rule` like that.  `required:` normally accepts only `true` or `false`.  However, you could also use [`depends`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) in order to specify a function inside of a `true/false` `rule`...

```
rules: {
    tables: {
        required: {
            depends:  function(element) {
                return $("#individual").val() === 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, using the above, your form will always pass validation because both fields are never empty (*they contain "0"*).  Therefore, the `required` rule is always satisfied.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/vcnt9/

You cannot fix it by removing the default value of `0` from the two fields, since the `depends` function will never be satisfied and the fields simply remain optional.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/vcnt9/1/

Alternately, you cannot fix this by applying `depends` to the `min: 1` rule, since it's only allowed for use with a rule that is either `true` or `false`.

---

The best solution is to [use `addMethod` to create your own rule](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage) for these two fields.  Use "less than or equal to" operators, ( `<=` ), to exclude negative numbers.

```
$.validator.addMethod("myMethod", function (value, element) {
    if (($("#individual").val() <= 0) && ($("#tables").val() <= 0)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}, "Please enter at least one field");
```

**Working Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/v4UGM/**